# Which css code do I need to give my menu a nice dropflow?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu like this:

```
<div class="menu-hori" id="myMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myResponsive()">&#9776;</a></li>
        <li><a>1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Sub 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>SubSub 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click the hamburger icon in the top ListItem, the menu opens. So the functionality is fine. Though it does not look nice, how can I use css to give it a smooth fold out? A nice flow down?

Comment: What is your css code? Please include a working example. What exactly do you want to achieve? Would a simple transistion be enough?

Comment: yes a transition! But I don't know what is possible, I just want is to slide down nicely instead of just appearing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions